# Merging two lists with multiple rows and columns

Tags: python-3.x, list, matrix, multiple-columns

Hi I have the following two lists:

```
list1 = [[(10.0, 10.0, 0.0), (90.0, 10.0, 0.0), (90.0, 90.0, 0.0), (10.0, 90.0, 0.0)]]
list2 = [[(15.0, 7.0, 0.0), (40.0, 15.0, 0.0), (20.0, 30.0, 0.0), (11.0, 67.0, 0.0)]]
```

How do I merge them in order to look like:

```
10.0, 10.0, 0.0, 15.0, 7.0, 0.0
90.0, 10.0, 0.0, 40.0, 15.0, 0.0
90.0, 90.0, 0.0, 20.0, 30.0, 0.0
10.0, 90.0, 0.0, 11.0, 67.0, 0.0
```

If tryed different solutions but always ended with an error or the wrong representation. Is there also a way to adress every element seperatly? Maybe with index?

Answer (score 1):

With `numpy` module, built-in `zip()` and `itertools.chain.from_iterable()` functions:

```
import itertools, numpy as np

list1 = [[(10.0, 10.0, 0.0), (90.0, 10.0, 0.0), (90.0, 90.0, 0.0), (10.0, 90.0, 0.0)]]
list2 = [[(15.0, 7.0, 0.0), (40.0, 15.0, 0.0), (20.0, 30.0, 0.0), (11.0, 67.0, 0.0)]]

chain = list(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(i)) for i in zip(list1[0], list2[0]))
arr = np.array(chain, dtype=float)

print(arr)
```

The output:

```
[[ 10.  10.   0.  15.   7.   0.]
 [ 90.  10.   0.  40.  15.   0.]
 [ 90.  90.   0.  20.  30.   0.]
 [ 10.  90.   0.  11.  67.   0.]]
```

---

Now, you are able to "*address every element seperatly*".

Let's say we want to get the **4**th value from the **last** row:

```
print(arr[3,3])  # 11.0
```

Comment: thank you. Is there a way to adress each element seperately? For example I want to compare the second element in the third row with the forth element in the second row?

Comment: thanks, I got it.
Regarding the `numpy` and especialy `np.insert`. Is there a way to insert str as well? `result = np.insert(result, 1, 'G01', axis=1)`gets me an error `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'G01'`

Comment: @Rob-In, to deal with string values you should define the array with appropriate datatype `dtype` :  `arr = np.array(chain, dtype=str)
` OR `arr = np.array(chain, dtype=object)`